# Getting rid of unwanted html in file

Tags: powershell

I have a file that has the following below, I am trying to remove everything from `<!--` to `-->`

```
<!--<br>
/* Font Definitions */

-->
Only keep this part
```

Comment: Hi I am new to this site I am using powershell I didn't meant to put r there. Basically I am trying to remove html from a file.

Comment: I've updated the tag so the correct people see this.

Comment: Don't use a regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use a regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) HTML isn't a regular language, so it can't be properly parsed with a regex. It will succeed most of the time, but other times will fail. Spectacularly.

I recommend cracking open the file, and reading it a character at at time, looking for the characters `<`, `!`, `-`, followed by `-`. Then, continue reading until you find `-`, `-`, `!`, followed by `>`.

```
$chars = [IO.File]::ReadAllText( $path ).ToCharArray()
$newFileContent = New-Object 'Text.StringBuilder'
for( $i = 0; $i -lt $chars.Length; ++$i )
{
    if( $inComment )
    {
        if( $chars[$i] -eq '-' -and $chars[$i+1] -eq '-' -and $chars[$i+2] -eq '!' -and $chars[$i+3] -eq '>' )
        {
            $inComment = $false
            $i += 4
        }
        continue
    }

    if( $chars[$i] -eq '<' -and $chars[$i+1] -eq '!' -and $chars[$i+2] -eq '-' -and $chars[$i+3] -eq '-' )
    {
        $inComment = $true
        $i += 4
        continue
    }

    $newFileContent.Append( $chars[$i] )
}
$newFileContent.ToString() | Set-Content -Path $path
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions to the rescue again -

```
@'
<!--<br>
/* Font Definitions */

-->
Only keep this part 
'@ -replace '(?s)<!--(.+?)-->', ''
```

`(?s)` makes dot match new lines :)